# Putting solutions next to T/F choices

Tags: positioning, exam, shading

**Setup**

I have the following MWE:

```
  \documentclass[addpoints,12pt]{exam}

  \usepackage{color}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{amssymb}

  \checkboxchar{$\Box$}
  \checkedchar{$\blacksquare$}

  \bracketedpoints
  \shadedsolutions
  \renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{Solution:}\par\noindent}


  \begin{document}

  \textbf{\textsc{True/False:}  [1pt each]}
  \vspace{0.1in}
   \begin{questions}

   \question Every normal distribution has a bell-shaped graph.

   \begin{oneparcheckboxes}
   \correctchoice T
   \choice F
   \end{oneparcheckboxes}

   \question If $X$ is a binomial random variable, then $X$ is approx. normal.

  \begin{oneparcheckboxes}
  \choice T
  \correctchoice F
  \end{oneparcheckboxes}

  \question Why did the chicken cross the road?
  \begin{solution}[1.0in]
  To get to the other side!
  \end{solution}

  \end{questions}
  \end{document}
```

Which produces a perfectly fine (short) exam.  Now if I add the `answers` option - that is, change the first line to `\documentclass[addpoints,12pt,answers]{exam}` - then I will get the correct T/F choices bubbled in, and a solution for the short answer question.

**Question**

What I'd like to also do is add a short one-line solution next to each T/F question, with some reasoning.  This solution would:

- have shaded background
- be on the same line as the T and F choices
- only be present when the `answers` option is given

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created `\explanation`, to be added at the end of the T/F `oneparcheckboxes` environment.

```
  \documentclass[addpoints,12pt,answers]{exam}

  \usepackage{color}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{amssymb}

  \checkboxchar{$\Box$}
  \checkedchar{$\blacksquare$}

  \bracketedpoints
  \shadedsolutions
  \renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{Solution:}\par\noindent}
  \definecolor{SolutionColor}{gray}{0.8}
  \def\explanation#1{%
    \ifprintanswers\mdseries\colorbox{SolutionColor}{\strut #1}\fi}

  \begin{document}

  \textbf{\textsc{True/False:}  [1pt each]}
  \vspace{0.1in}
   \begin{questions}

   \question Every normal distribution has a bell-shaped graph.

   \begin{oneparcheckboxes}
   \correctchoice T 
   \choice F
   \explanation{Explanation goes here}
   \end{oneparcheckboxes}

   \question If $X$ is a binomial random variable, then $X$ is approx. normal.

  \begin{oneparcheckboxes}
  \choice T
  \correctchoice F
   \explanation{Another explanation goes here}
  \end{oneparcheckboxes}

  \question Why did the chicken cross the road?
  \begin{solution}[1.0in]
  To get to the other side!
  \end{solution}

  \end{questions}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I had in mind! Two optional questions: (1) can I change the spacing between the "F" and the shaded box? (2) What happens if my explanation goes longer than a line? I will try this out as soon as I get home.  Again, thanks!

Comment: Try `\def\explanation#1{\ifprintanswers\mdseries\hspace{1em}\colorbox{SolutionColor}{\parbox[t]{2in}{#1}}\fi}`